# Filter .json files to remove ones with null records

Tags: json, bash, shell, scripting

I've got a folder containing thousands of `.json` files named thigs like `99.json` (the numbers are sequential). Some of them contain valid records but others just contain `null` on a single line. I want to filter out the files that only contain `null` so they don't screw up my next step of processing. Surely this is easy but I can't immediately see how to do it.

It would help, as an additional step, to combine the valid files (the ones with complete or partially complete records) into a single file as a list. But this is less important.

All suggestions gratefully appreciated. Many thanks.

Comment: null as a series of four characters spelling out the word `null`

Comment: Is it always present in the first line? Also Is it OK to append valid file contents one after the other, to create one big file

Comment: All the invalid files I've looked at so far just have the word `null` on the first line with no end-of-line character.

Comment: It would be fine to append them all into one big file, provided that file is valid `.json`. So I guess the valid results would need to become a list.

Comment: It would also be fine to move the valid files into another directory or to modify their names somehow so I can use a filter during the next stage of processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find all files with null's and group them as a list, you can use

```
grep *.json -e "null" >> badfiles.txt
```

To find all files with valid values and group them as a list, you can use

```
grep -v *.json -e "null" >> goodfiles.txt
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked once I changed `null` to `null$` to exclude the files that had `null` elsewhere as part of a valid record.